# What is the replacement for the xwd utility (X Window Dump) with Wayland (or even RHEL9)

Tags: x11, wayland, screenshot

I have old software that uses the program xwd to save graphics files (to make movies, or figures in papers).

xwd exists as a utility in RHEL8 (and Rocky Linux 8) but in Rocky Linux 9 (and one presumes RHEL9) this no longer exists.

Under Wayland, it appears this is going to be not available at all (as it's a security issue?)  I'm guessing there has to be some way (hopefully not Gnome, KDE, or... specific) to save a graphics image of a window.

Is there a generic "replacement" for the functionality of xwd?

To be clear, I'm still using X11 on RL9, as I'm also using NVIDIA's gpu libs.  But I will eventually need to get this working on Wayland also.

Comment: It depends on the compositor. See [grim](https://wayland.emersion.fr/grim/) as a possible tool.

Comment: Nice to see a possible "way" to wayland, but I'm actually still in X11 (as I've got nvidia/gpu coding).  I have grabbed slurp, and will likely grab grim, but they don't help with the x11 I'm still using.

Comment: `xwd` still exists in Fedora 38, in its own rpm. Perhaps it is hidden in some other package in your distribution. You can also use more popular programs like `gimp` to get parts of the screen (interactively), or `imagemagick` (use a command like `magick x: /tmp/out.xwd`).

Comment: This worked, once I figured out how to get the rpm from the correct repo!  This installed w/o problems on a RL9 system, which is using the Nvidia (and CUDA) drivers.  Longer term, I'll need to figure out something else, but this is a major help to me now.  Much, much thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is really given by [meuh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/119298/meuh) above, but wanted to get this clarified in case others have this issue.  Fedora 38's rpms:

```
xwd-1.0.8-4.fc38.x86_64 

xwud-1.0.6-3.fc38.x86_64
```

taken from one of the fedora mirrors, installed and seem to work perfectly.  Legacy software is functional again, I'll put in a note to it's maintainers, but in the mean time I have xwd (and it's inverse, xwud) back in my toolbox.

Intrigued to see someone who has a longer acquaintence with Unix than I do.  I believe mine starts in 1979, I used cards or DEC operating systems before that point.  Much, much thanks [meuh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/119298/meuh)!